# Which oil is best for Zeppole?

Tags: frying, doughnuts

Which oil is best for frying Italian doughnuts?

Answer (score 3):

I've made thousands of Zeppole throughout my career.

Don't use olive oil, you'll impart the wrong flavour profile.

Veg/Canola/Peanut, or any other neutrally flavoured high-temp oil suitable for frying will work.

PERSONALLY, I prefer Zeppole and other choux paste products baked on a parchment sheet, with a light mist of cooking spray.

Answer (score -3):

I would expect Italians to use Olive oil.

I'd use whatever feels right for frying (peanut oil, canola...)

Comment: I’d expect them to use lard.

Comment: Olive oil is too fragile for most (if not all) deep frying temperatures.